# How to call a function inside a data class

Tags: kotlin, set

I have this data class that has a function inside and I want to use the function to add element to the data class' set but I'm not sure how to call it.

This is the code:

```
data class House(val article: MutableSet<Article>){

   //only add articles if there are less than 10
   fun addArticle(article: Article): Boolean{

       if(articles.size <= 10){
           articles.add(article)
           return true
       } else {
           return false
       }
   }
}

data class Article(val type: String,
                  var color: String)

val article1 = Article("bed", "black")
val article2 = Article("sheets", "white")

val articlesToAdd = House(mutableSetOf(article1, article2))
   
//add articles to house: THIS DOESN'T WORK

articlesToAdd.forEach{
   it.house.addVehicle()
}
```

So, I want to be able to add articles to my house by using the addArticle function inside of the data class House but the way I've thought of doing it doesn't work. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`articlesToAdd` is of type `House` therefore it doesn't have a method `forEach`. Here's a sample which adds one more `Article`.

```
val article1 = Article("bed", "black")
val article2 = Article("sheets", "white")

val articles = mutableSetOf(article1, article2)

val house = House(articles)

house.addArticle( Article("bed", "red"))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but how can I do this without passing the articles yet (as I can only add a limit of 20 and if I add them in house first, they are already passed and I cannot addArticle).

Comment: First of all, your limit is 10 (it’s in your code) and not 20. Second of all, Yayotron provided you with the correct answer but now you’re saying that you don’t want to pass the articles yet to the house? Your response is quite confusing.

Comment: You can certainly add more articles to the house by calling house.addArticle() with a new mutableSet of articles without affecting what are already in “articles” object. Try it